# Limit the generate pdf to one page only? html2pdf library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, html2pdf

I'm trying to limit the pdf to one page only, is there a way that I can put limit to it?

Below the code:

```
function generatePDF() {
  // Choose the element that our invoice is rendered in.
  const element = document.getElementById("content-certificate");
  // Choose the element and save the PDF for our user.
  var opt = {
    filename: 'sample.pdf', 
    image: {type: 'jpg', quality: 0.2}, 
    html2canvas: {dpi: 192, letterRendering: true, useCORS: true}, 
    jsPDF: {unit: 'pt', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait'            
  }};
  html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was having several blank pages after the first page which contains the real content so I looped through the whole document and removed all the blank pages. This didn't fix the blank pages bug (I didn't find out what is causing it).

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    let pWidth = 595.28; // the width of a4
    let srcWidth = document.querySelector("body > div").scrollWidth;
    let margin = 18; // narrow margin - 1.27 cm (36);
    let scale = (pWidth - margin * 2) / srcWidth;
    let pdf = new  jspdf.jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4", true);
    pdf.html(document.querySelector("body > div"), {
        x: margin,
        y: margin,
        html2canvas: {
            scale: scale,
        },
        callback: function (_pdf) {
            var totalPages = _pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();

            for (var i = 2; i <= totalPages; i++) {
                // Go to each page after the first and delete it
                _pdf.setPage(i);
                _pdf.deletePage(i);
                i--;
                totalPages--;
            }
            window.open(_pdf.output("bloburl"));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set a fixed height for "content-certificate" component. But, this will restrict the library from generating more pdf pages in case if you have more content to print.

Comment: Please provide some context, just putting the error message as the question is not helpful. Also consider tagging the quest.

Comment: @ErionS What post have you been trying to comment? I can't seem to make the connection to this answer.